# checking all checkboxes at once in gridview

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics, windows-forms-designer, ultrawingrid

I have mapped ultra grid to bit value column and it shows check boxes in that column.I can select one by one and update to database but i want to check all check boxes at once by pressing a button or something else.How can i do this.

Comment: i am using windows forms application with infragistics ultragrid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing you have an UltraWinGrid with only one band this code will loop over every row and select or unselect the column in question

```
public void SetSelection(string colName, bool sel)
{
    foreach(UltraGridRow r in grid.Rows)
    {
        if(r.IsDataRow == true)
           r.Cells[colName].Value = sel;
    }
}
```

Did you know that in the latest versions of UltraGrid there is the functionality to add a checkbox in the header of the boolean column to allow the checking/unchecking of all columns directly from that check

```
 gridCol.Header.CheckBoxAlignment = HeaderCheckBoxAlignment.Left;
 gridCol.Header.CheckBoxSynchronization = HeaderCheckBoxSynchronization.RowsCollection;
 gridCol.Header.CheckBoxVisibility = HeaderCheckBoxVisibility.WhenUsingCheckEditor;
```

Answer (score 0):

**check all checkboxes in another checkbox click**

```
function SelectAll(id) {
        var frm = document.forms[0];
        for (i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++){
                if (frm.elements[i].type == 'checkbox')
                {
                    frm.elements[i].checked = document.getElementById(id).checked;
                }             
        }
    }
```